# What does FlexRs=SPEED_OPTIMIZED do in Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The `--flexRSGoal=COST_OPTIMIZED` is obvious for me, but in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/flexrs#pipeline_options) I also see `SPEED_OPTIMIZED`, how does it work?

Does Dataflow use preemptible VMs without flexRS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag is documented in more detail in the [execution parameters guide](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-exec-params#setting-other-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-options), which states:

> If unspecified, defaults to SPEED_OPTIMIZED, which is the same as omitting this flag. To turn on FlexRS, you must specify the value COST_OPTIMIZED to allow the Dataflow service to choose any available discounted resources.

So `SPEED_OPTIMIZED` does not enable FlexRS, it requests normal Dataflow behavior.

Regarding preemptible VMs: No, Dataflow does not use preemptible VMs unless FlexRS is enabled.

Comment: Hey, how do we enable FlexRS in beam job for Golang. Is it just passing the parameter? Is it just adding additional parameter --flexrs_goal=COST_OPTIMIZED ?

Comment: I get the error `flag provided but not defined: -flexrs_goal`

Comment: @impossible Unfortunately Dataflow doesn't officially support Golang jobs yet, and FlexRS support hasn't been implemented in the SDK yet (hence why there is no flexrs_goal flag defined).